# Teensy read two encoders simultaneously

Tags: interrupts, encoder, dma, teensy, quadrature

I am trying to read two Quadrature encoders at exactly the same time. They are 4000CPR encoders, and they will be spinning between 10 to 60 RPM.

The two encoders are mechanically paired to the same motor, so they will spin identically, and I need to grab both values at exactly the same time. I will use either a Teensy 3.2, 3.6, 4.0 or an Arduino Uno.

How can I read both at the same time? Usually, you tie the A+ and B+ lines of the quadrature encoder to interrupt pins, and every time they change the software loop interrupts out to count the increment. However, if I read two encoders at the same time, how can I interrupt into two parallel paths?

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: "*the two encoders are mechanically paired to the same motor, so they will spin identically,*" What is the purpose of the two encoders then? Redundancy? Are you aligning them?

Comment: ‘Exactly at the same time’ how exact? There is going to be some error, so determine the amount of error is acceptable. I’d suggest setting up a timer interrupt at around 10kHz and have the isr read the four port pins and decode the quadrature. Are you wanting to do torque measurement by measuring the phase difference with the encoders?

Comment: `Usually, you tie the A+ and B+ lines of the quadrature encoder to interrupt pins` ... no, connect only one line to the interrupt pin ... read the state of the other line to determine the direction of rotation

Comment: Just to add more fuel to the fire, the meaning isn't clear when you write "4000CPR". Do you mean 4000 rising and falling edges of both A and B channels? Or something different?

Comment: Note: using real world signals connected to interrupts requires some care. There needs to be filtering or some form of rate limiting so that any interference that causes a slew of interrupts doesn’t cripple the processor.

Comment: _"how can I interrupt into two parallel paths?"_ - why do you want two 'parallel paths'?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Dual Core or VLIW? ;)

Comment: @jonk On an Arduino UNO, yeah right :). The OP needs to clarify exactly what they want to do.